# Javascript file not loading in aspx ? ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want this type of functionality in my project.

Here is [the JS Bin link](http://jsbin.com/xikikamufa/3/edit?html,css,js,output).

There are 3 files `stylesheet.css`, `javascript.js` and a html file.

I'm trying in Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET C# but it is not working: the Javascript file is not loaded.

**ASPX code:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**StyleSheet.css**:

```
body {
}

#editor {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: monospace;
    display:block;
}

.statement {
    color: orange;
}
```

**JScript.js**:

```
$("#editor").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").trim();
    var word = text.split(" ");
    var newHTML = "";

    $.each(word, function (index, value) {
        switch (value.toUpperCase()) {
            case "SELECT":
            case "FROM":
            case "WHERE":
            case "LIKE":
            case "BETWEEN":
            case "NOT LIKE":
            case "FALSE":
            case "NULL":
            case "FROM":
            case "TRUE":
            case "NOT IN":
                newHTML += "<span class='statement'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
                break;
            default:
                newHTML += "<span class='other'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
        }
    });
    $(this).html(newHTML);

    //// Set cursor postion to end of text
    var child = $(this).children();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    $(this)[0].focus();
}
});
```

`JScript.js` file is not working. `Keyword` color not changing but i provided the link its working fine.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked console? Also you script file is using `$` which means this file needs `jQuery` or subsets. Load them

Comment: What do you mean with the file not being loaded? Bad request? Wrong URL (404)? Errors in the console? I can't see you loading `jQuery` before using it...

Comment: @Rajesh how can i check in console?

Comment: @MelanciaUK no error ,i already tell you that color not changing just.

Comment: You're missing some basics here, like how to load the browser console. Press F12.

Comment: @Rajesh here is console error `JScript.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @Ashley you can refer following link for reference: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: Bingo! You're not loading the `jQuery` library that you're trying to use.

Comment: @MelanciaUK how can i use tell me solution

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: Refer [how-jquery-works](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Sorry same problem occur.Not working .Here is screenshot [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/UFgJqQH.png)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Here is output [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/jvsALCg.png)

Comment: You're loading it in the wrong place (`body`, after loading your own `JS` file). I honestly suggest that you look for tutorials on how to work with `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript` before going any further.

Comment: @Rajesh I provide my screenshot after install jqeury.Watch please

Comment: @MelanciaUK I place in body because i provided you `JSBIN` link and i follow this link,in this link `jscript` provided in body you can see

Comment: @MelanciaUK i correct my `jscript` link.Now i put in above body in head .There is no error in console now.But still not working.Here is screeshot [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/nY18FA6.png)

Comment: @Ashley [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh47qhc1/). You can check on JSFiddle. I'm not sure but JSBin. Have not used much.

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry so say but i don't need in `JSFiddle` or any other.I want just works in my project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I suggested in the comments, you would benefit from some tutorials on how to work not just with `jQuery`, but also with `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript`. You're lacking some very basic knowledge to be able to work with the stack.
I'm answering your question just to give you a headstart:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Loading the jQuery library before everything else. 
        Getting it from Google CDN, but you can have it locally. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Loading your own Javascript file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Your `Javascript` code should be wrapped within a `document ready` event handler:

```
$(function () {
    // Your code goes here.
});
```

From what I understood from your code, you're trying to *highlight* some words when typing `SQL` script in the box.
It's working just fine: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/kut46oq2/)

More info:

[jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)

[Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)

Comment: Thanks a'lot for reply @MelancialUK.I follow your instructions but stills not working .There is no error in `console` but still not working.Color not changing

Comment: Sorry to say but i can't understand your this instruction `Your Javascript code should be wrapped within a document ready event handler:`

Comment: Have a read on the `jQuery Learning Center`. I can't just write an answer here explaining `jQuery` bit by bit. It's not the purpose of this forum I'm afraid.

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding a demo with your code. It's working just fine after loading the libraries correctly.

Comment: Ouhhh Thankss.Great!! Now working fine.I copy your demo code .Lolx .Thanks

Comment: Here's a _better_ way of doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/kut46oq2/2/. It will highlight your text when the page is loaded aswell as while you're typing.